# Appending parameter to existing URL cause infinite loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a page `index.php`, I want to append a parameter to the end of URL upon a certain action by user. So the result would be `index.php?param=1`

Using the below PHP code causing an infinite redirect loop.

```
<?php 
header("Location: index.php?param=1");
?>
```

Using the below Javascript code result in infinite refresh loop.

```
window.location = "?param=1";
```

How can I append that parameter only once without encountering any loop using either PHP, Javascript or jQuery?

Comment: Where are you redirecting *from*?  If loading the index page redirects to the index page, then that would definitely be an infinite redirect loop.  Of course, if you're already *on* the index page when performing the redirect, then you don't *need* to redirect.  So it's not really clear what you're trying to do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the PHP version, try:

```
<?php
    if( !isset( $_GET['param'] ) ){
        header('location: index.php?param=1' );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try add host name and then try.

Example - If you are using localhost.

```
<?php 
header("Location: http://localhost/index.php?param=1");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you could check if the additional parameter is already set, e.g.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
    header("Location: index.php?param=1");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use `.htaccess` files to set redirects due to there is the good practice to store logic and server configuration separately.

Here is `.htaccess` code for you:

```
Redirect /path/to/index.php http://yourdomain.com/path/to/index.php?param=1
```

or if you need to have permanent redirect use

```
Redirect 301 /path/to/index.php http://yourdomain.com/path/to/index.php?param=1
```

If you do not use Apache but Nginx or something else check their documentation how to make redirects. Typically it is very easy.